# Can you reprogram the motorola-droid-razr-m screen buttons? Does it require Rooting?

Tags: buttons, motorola-droid-razr

I'm not a big fan of the Droid-Razr-M's screen buttons (missing the menu and search buttons, but includes a Programs button (which is a waste b/c you can long hold the Home button for that).

Since those buttons are actually on the screen, can you reprogram them?
Would it require rooting the phone?

Comment: Looking at this motorola's site for specific model, in short - it does not require reprogramming, or rooting, it requires a custom rom, looking at [CyanogenMod](http://www.cyanogenmod.org/devices) it is not listed, best bet would be to try XDA. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this would be helpful, but I love this app called Button Savior, which provides on-screen access to many of the functions you would find only via hard buttons.  You can activate it by a simple swipe, or by pressing a very translucent button that's always on the screen.  Some of the functions do require that you have rooted your phone, but not all.

Comment: Button Saviour comes in two flavours. [Button saviour (non root)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smart.swkey.nonroot) as the name says does not require a root access. [Button saviour (root)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smart.swkey) requires root access to perform more tasks that its non root version cannot do.